# iPhone App to limit the data usage to 10 Gt?

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there any application to limit the data usage to certain amount in iPhone?

*P.s. I tested Onavos such as [here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/onavo/id423545287?mt=8&ls=1) but it is very slow with me so uninstalled. Also Data Usage [app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/data-usage/id386950560?mt=8) but poor ratings.*

Answer (score 1):

The following looks the most promising apps and recommended [here](http://voip.about.com/od/voipbandwidth/tp/Data-Usage-Monitor-Apps-For-Your-Iphone-And-Ipad.htm).

- My Data Usage Pro [here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my-data-usage-pro/id396349239?mt)
- DataMan [here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dataman-real-time-data-usage/id404513413?mt=8)